# Notice: Undefined variable when creating shortcode for The Events Calendar by Modern Tribe

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined, shortcode

I found a tutorial that allows me to create a shortcode for "The Events Calendar by Modern Tribe" that allows me to display a list of recent events. The code works and displays the list correctly but I get a notice that says "Notice: Undefined variable: no_upcoming_events in mysite/themes/theme-name/recent_events.php on line 40"

This is the line that it is referring to:

```
if ( $posts && !$no_upcoming_events) {
```

And this is the complete code:

```
function ckhp_get_tribe_events($atts) {

    if ( !function_exists( 'tribe_get_events' ) ) { 
        return;
    }

    global $wp_query, $tribe_ecp, $post;
    $output='';
    $ckhp_event_tax = '';

    extract( shortcode_atts( array( 
        'cat' => '', 
        'number' => 5,
        'error' => 'y' 
    ), $atts, 'ckhp-tribe-events' ), EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'ckhp' );

    if ( $ckhp_cat ) {
        $ckhp_event_tax = array( 
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $ckhp_cat
            ) 
        );
    }

    $posts = tribe_get_events(apply_filters('tribe_events_list_widget_query_args', array(
            'eventDisplay' => 'upcoming',
            'posts_per_page' => $ckhp_number,
            'tax_query'=> $ckhp_event_tax
    )));

    if ( $posts && !$no_upcoming_events) {

        $output .= '<ul class="hfeed vcalendar ckhp-small ckhp-event-list">';
        foreach( $posts as $post ) :
            setup_postdata( $post );
            $output .= '<li class="">';
            $output .= '<h4 class="entry-title summary">' . '<a href="' . tribe_get_event_link() . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() . '</a>' . '</h4>';
            $output .= '<div class="duration venue">' . tribe_events_event_schedule_details() . ' ' . tribe_get_venue() . '</div>';
            $output .= '</li>';
        endforeach;
        $output .= '</ul><!-- .hfeed -->';
        $output .= '<p class="tribe-events-widget-link"><a href="' . tribe_get_events_link() . '" rel="bookmark">' . translate( 'View All Events', 'tribe-events-calendar' ) . '</a></p>';

    } else { //No Events were Found
        $output .= ( $ckhp_error == 'y' ? '<p>' . translate( 'There are no upcoming events at this time.', 'tribe-events-calendar' ) . '</p>' : '' ) ;
    } // endif

    wp_reset_query();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('ckhp-tribe-events', 'ckhp_get_tribe_events'); // link new function to shortcode name
```

I'm not too skilled with php so I'm not sure what I need to do to remove this notice. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems that variable is sometimes initialized and sometimes not. Add following before if statement `if(! isset($no_upcoming_events) ) $no_upcoming_events=0; if ( $posts && !$no_upcoming_events) {`

Comment: What happens if you set no_upcoming_events = ""; at the beginning of your function and let it get set normally when the function is called and data is passed to it?

Comment: Can you do a search within all relevant files for any definition of `$no_upcoming_events`? It's strange that it is sometimes initialised and sometimes not. Unfortunately the source needs to be known before you do a solution like @Mr.Concolato recommended becuase you will probably end up changing functionality of this script ($no_upcoming_events will always be false).

Comment: @Scopey I am 100% sure that ` extract( shortcode_atts( array( ` sometimes exports-extracts $no_upcoming_events ie when there are no events it is set to true. Poorly written code but that is PHP , allow anybody to make a script that will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't require explicit declaration/initialization of variables (which is handy sometimes) but can cause issues like these.

The most elegant solution is simply to check that the variable is set to something before testing what that something is.

```
if ( $posts && isset($no_upcoming_events) && !$no_upcoming_events ) {
    ...
}
```

If `$no_upcoming_events` isn't set, the `isset` fails and the `if` statement exits (short circuits) and never checks the value of `$no_upcoming_events`, avoiding the error.